# what does convergence in locally integrable function space mean?

Tags: calculus

For example, $f$ and $f_n$  are locally integrable functions defined in a set $U$. What does it mean by
$f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L_{loc}(U)$?
I think it means that for any compact subset $K$ in $U$, $\int_K|f_n-f|$ is converging to zero as $n$ is approaching infinity.
But I am not sure. Can any one give me a precise definition? or a relevant reference ?

Comment: yes, it means exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function). As a metric you can take 
$$d(f,g)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}\frac{\Vert f-g\Vert_{L^p(K_n)}}{1+\Vert f-g\Vert_{L^p(K_n)}},$$
where $K_n$ is an increasing sequence of compact sets with $\cup_n K_n=\Omega$