# Convergence in $L^p_{\operatorname{ loc}}(\Omega)$ for some $p\ge1$ implies convergence in $L^q_{\operatorname{ loc}}(\Omega)$ for all $q \ge 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

> I need to show that if we have a sequence $\{ f_n\}$ uniformly bounded in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, and $f_n \to f$ in $L^p_{\operatorname{  loc} }(\Omega)$ for some $p \ge 1$ and $\Omega$ be undounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $f_n \to f$ in $L^q_{\operatorname{  loc}}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ for all $q \in [1, \infty)$

I could see that this is true for all  $q\le p$  using Holder's inequality. How can I prove for $p \le q$.

Comment: What is "undounded", what is $\Omega$ (is it open?) and how did $\Omega$ turn into $\mathbb R^n?$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $p\leqslant q$. According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364822/what-does-convergence-in-locally-integrable-function-space-mean), it suffices to prove that if $C\subset\mathbb R$ is compact, then $\int_C\left\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\right\rvert^q\mathrm dx \to 0$. To this aim, observe that 
$$\left\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\right\rvert^q=\left\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\right\rvert^p \left\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\right\rvert^{q-p} \\ \leqslant \left\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\right\rvert^p2^{q-p}\left( \left\lvert f_n(x)\right\rvert^{q-p}  +\left\lvert  f(x)\right\rvert   ^{q-p}\right)      
    \leqslant \left\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\right\rvert^p 2^{q-p}   \sup_{t\in\mathbb R}\left\lvert f_n(t)\right\rvert^q +\left\lvert f(t)\right\rvert^q    .$$
It is actually the case $p\gt q$ which follows from Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on this inequality

Comment: @MathMan I have added more details.